# Populate a column based on shared value in another column in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

[image: Input data]

[image: Output data]

The top image is the input data, and the bottom image is the desired output.

For all items within the same family, I want to add the value for `child` when `sort >= 50`. In the simplest case (and the majority), there is only a single row with `sort >= 50`. There are some cases with multiple rows `sort >= 50`. If I could figure out the simplest case first, I could even manually do the others.

This isn't really merging the two columns, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: 1) You mean `sort >= 50`? 1) What if there are multiple rows in the family with `sort >= 50`? 2) What if there are no rows in the family with a `sort >= 50`?

Comment: Your data has no row with sort >= 50, how come you want 78461? Where did you get that number?

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out the child for each family. Since there can be more than one row with `sort >= 50` in a family we'll use [row_number](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-row_number/) to rank them, highest sort value first.

Then join with that. I've chosen to use the row with the highest sort. I've used a left join in case any families don't have a matching parent row.

```sql
with parents as (
  select
    family, child,
    row_number() over (
      partition by family
      order by sort desc
    ) as priority
  from stuff
  where sort >= 50
)
select
  stuff.family, stuff.sort, stuff.collection, parents.child
from stuff
left join parents on
  stuff.family = parents.family and
  parents.priority = 1
;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/8OI5_qr3).